# GKE CloudRun - resource control on request level

Tags: serverless-framework, google-cloud-run

I wonder how to increase the number of CPU cores available per individual  request on GKE based CloudRun deployed container.
While it is possible to specify `--cpu` option to control service limit, I was unable to find way to control request CPU allocation

```
    spec:
      container:
        image: us.gcr.io/myrepo/myimage
        env:
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: '8'
         requests:
           cpu: 400m
```

I also wonder if it is possible to specify `--timeout` greater than 10 min?

Comment: Timeout is being worked on, referenced in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56139697/how-to-increase-15-minutes-request-timeout-for-google-cloud-run-service-deployed

Comment: I've seen it recently, interestingly some of my request took 15 min, and when they completed I got log with my service time taken, but the client got gateway timeout after 10 min, any ETA with cloud run